# Vim - Vi // Substitute pattern

Tags: vim, replace, find, vi

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<Word name="name1" WordID="...">
</Word>
```

I need to insert 2 extra leading spaces in front of  both such lines, in the whole file
Any ideas? - Thanks!

Comment: Are you having trouble with the regular expression or the replacement command?

Comment: Davis, with the regular expression, since it has to include both cases and the special characters "<" and "/" simultanously
The lines have to start with  <Word   and  </Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
%s/^\(<\/*[Ww]ord.*\)$/  \1/
```

% means whole file.

s means substitute

^ means start of line

$ means end of line

< is the angle bracket

.* means any character zero or more times

( and ) enclose the regular expression you want to keep

\1 indicates where the regular expression kept should be inserted.

After `/` and before `\1` you insert as many spaces as you want.

When you write an expression between `\(` and `\)` it is recorded and can be used afterwards with `\N` where N is a number.
For example here `\1` means the first expression matched.
If you had `\(` and `\)` a second time, you could use `\1` and `\2` to include the first and the second one respectively.

For example,

```
s/\(first\)\(second\)/\1 \2/
```

will insert a space between the words first and second

Comment: Edited my answer to address your reply to Davis's comment. Note that \\ is the expression to match \, since it is a special character.

Comment: Sarj, your command almost solved the issue.  It had to be modified to:
%s/^\(<\/*[Ww]ord.*\)$/  \1/
since the special char was "/"
But can you please elaborate on the use of  \1/  what exactly does? What if for example I want 3 leading spaces? - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've addressed your question editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: global command.

Global commands act on the entire file, and perform an (Ex) action on each line that matches the pattern. It’s the inspiration for `grep` (`:global/re/print`), and resembles `awk` if you squint.

Our action here is to insert two spaces, which, semantically, is less-well captured by a `substitute` to my brain.

Since we need an Ex command, we use `:normal!` to execute a normal command with no mappings applied, and then simply `I`nsert two spaces at the beginning of the line.

(I copied and edited the pattern from [N Sarj’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53908091/4400820))

```
:global ~</\?[Ww]ord~ normal! I
```

Take care to note the two trailing spaces after `I`.

Here I used `~` as a pattern separator because any character will do, and not using the standard `/` meant I didn’t need to escape it in the pattern.

We still must escape the `?` to get it’s special meaning of “zero or one” (as opposed to matching a literal `?`).

Comment: RE is missing a backslash before `?` and it would be good to explain why you used `~`.

Comment: @user7369280 lmk what you think